# USB flash drive partitioning exits without completing

Tags: partitioning, fat32

I have a 16 GB TDK flash drive with one fat32 partition and msdos partition table. On ubuntu 14.04 using gparted I am trying to resize this partition from ~14.4(16) GB to 12.4 and leave 2 GB of free space for a new partition to the end of the disk. When I click "apply changes" it starts and then it either freezes or crashes without completing then the Flash drive is fully useable without any problems but the partition wasn't resised.

Any suggestions? Is this a bug or a problem of the Flash Drive? I unmounted the partition before resizing.

Comment: When you watch the detailed progress section, can you add to your question at which operation it freezes or crashes?

Comment: I tried again to see where it freezes. It freezed while it was searching for filesystem errors and trying to repair them, as it said. The window freezed and I waited for 15 minutes.Both close and cancel buttons didn't work. I terminated the app using System Monitoring. When I opened gparted again it just disn't open. I rebooted and logged in while it was saying something like "System Program error detected" and it send a bug report (it was gparted). Does the filesystem has any unusual errors that gparted can't repair?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seemed like the fat32 partition had problems.
1. I copied the data from it to my hard drive.
2. I created a new msdos partition table.
3. I created 2 new partitions.
4. Copied the files back to the first partition again.
Now it works without having any problems.